My VGA driver set_char_in_mem function is not taking s[i] as input
So i am following a blog about building an os trying to build a simple kernel.I am on step 2 and am using VGA to display things
the function setcharinmem.
When i pass 'a' in it displays normally but when i pass a string index s[i] it doesn't work no errors just wont print anything
I have tried all kinds of different inputs to try to figure out the issue *(s+i) making a new variable char c = s[i] and passing that in none of those seem to work.Since manually giving 'a' and changing offset etc seems to work The issue seems be in memory where it just cannot get the char from string or something.
disp.h

#define VGA_CTR_REG 0x3d4
#define VGA_DATA_REG 0x3d5
#define VGA_OFFSET_LOW 0x0f
#define VGA_OFFSET_HIGH 0x0e
#define V_ADDR 0xb8000
#define MAX_R 25
#define MAX_C 80
#define W_ON_B 0x0f

unsigned char port_byte_in(unsigned short port){ 
    unsigned char res;          
    __asm__("in %%dx,%%al":"=a"(res):"d"(port));
    return res;                    
}

void port_byte_out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data){ 
    __asm__("out %%al,%%dx"::"a"(data),"d"(port));
}

void set_cursor(int offset){
    offset /= 2;               
    port_byte_out(VGA_CTR_REG, VGA_OFFSET_HIGH);
    port_byte_out(VGA_DATA_REG, (unsigned char)(offset >> 8));
    port_byte_out(VGA_CTR_REG, VGA_OFFSET_LOW);
    port_byte_out(VGA_DATA_REG, (unsigned char)(offset & 0xff));
}

int get_cursor(){
    port_byte_out(VGA_CTR_REG, VGA_OFFSET_HIGH);
    int offset = port_byte_in(VGA_DATA_REG) << 8;
    port_byte_out(VGA_CTR_REG, VGA_OFFSET_LOW);
    offset += port_byte_in(VGA_DATA_REG);
    return offset * 2;
}

void set_char_in_mem(char c, int offset){
    unsigned char *vidm = (unsigned char *) V_ADDR;
    vidm[offset] = c;
    vidm[offset + 1] = W_ON_B;
}

int get_row_from_offset(int offset) {
    return offset / (2 * MAX_C); 
}

int get_offset(int col, int row) {
    return 2 * (row * MAX_C + col);
}

int mov_offset_nl(int offset){
    return get_offset(0, get_row_from_offset(offset) + 1);
}

void cpy_chk(char * src, char* dst, int nbytes){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < nbytes; i++){
        *(dst + i) = *(src + i);
    }
}

int scr_ln(int offset){
    cpy_chk(
    (char*)(get_offset(0, 1) + V_ADDR),
    (char*)(get_offset(0, 0) + V_ADDR),
    MAX_C * (MAX_R - 1) * 2
    );
    for(int c = 0; c < MAX_C; c++){
        set_char_in_mem(' ', get_offset(c, MAX_R - 1));
    }
    return offset - (2 * MAX_C);
}

void cls(){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_C * MAX_R; i++){
        set_char_in_mem(' ', i * 2);
    }
    set_cursor(get_offset(0, 0));
}

void print_s(char* s){
    int offset = get_cursor();
    int i = 0;
    while(*(s + i) != 0){
        if(offset >= MAX_R * MAX_C * 2){
            offset = scr_ln(offset);
        }
        if(*(s + i) == '\n'){
            offset = mov_offset_nl(offset);
        } else {
            set_char_in_mem((char)*(s + i), offset);
            offset += 2;
        }
        i++;
    }
    set_cursor(offset);
}


kernel.c

#include "./drivers/disp.h"
void main() {
    cls();
    char* s = "this works ?";
    char c = s[0];
    int offset = get_offset(0, 0);
    int i = 0;
    set_char_in_mem('a', offset);
    set_cursor(offset + 2);
    offset += 2;

    //print_s("this works ?");
}


I will attach all the files here in case I messed up in a previous part.
mbr.asm
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

K_OFFSET equ 0x1000
mov [BOOT_DRV], dl

mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp

call load_k
call switch_to_32

jmp $

%include "d.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"
%include "switch_to_32.asm"

[bits 16]
load_k:
    mov bx, K_OFFSET
    mov dh, 2
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRV]
    call disk_l
    ret

[bits 32]
B_32Bit:
    call K_OFFSET
    jmp $
    
BOOT_DRV db 0
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55  ; magic bytes to show that this is the mbr



gdt.asm

gdt_start:
    dq 0x0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start -1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start



d.asm

disk_l:
    pusha
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, dh
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00

    int 0x13
    jc disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh

    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret

disk_error:
    jmp disk_loop

sectors_error:
    jmp disk_loop
disk_loop:
    jmp $

        

k_ent.asm

[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main

jmp $



switch_to_32.asm

[bits 16] 
switch_to_32:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32bit

[bits 32]
init_32bit:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call B_32Bit

    


Aside: you shouldn't have executable code in a header file.

The blog post is missing a linker script. Your c kernel is probably reading memory it isn't supposed to as it doesn't know where RODATA ends up in memory.

The function print_s() that "gets char from a string" isn't actually called in the code shown.

Uncommenting the //print_s("this works ?"); makes it work here. That is not to say that the code is correct, it might have some issue that does not affect my system.

@WeatherVane: at least not without static inline, then it's fine for short functions.

This sounds to me like your kernel.bin exceeds the number of sectors you are reading in your bootloader. In load_k you do mov dh, 2 . DH is the number of 512 byte sectors to read. A value of 2 is 512*2=1024. do ls -l kernel.bin to find the size of your kernel.bin. Add 511 to that size and then divide that result by 512. Round down to the nearest whole number. That should be the minimum you will need to put in DH . Likely your literal strings are in .rodata and beyond the kernel data your bootloader read into memory.

Many tutorials take short cuts and assume registers are in a certain state when your bootloader starts executing (especially the segment registers DS, ES, and SS). It is a false assumption but works in most emulators but you may find it won't work on some real hardware. I have some bootloader tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942

@MichaelPetch Thanks I increased the number of sectors I am loading and it worked.

@tkausl : while there may be no explicit script passed with -T, the usage of -Ttext to set the VMA of the first byte in the .text section doesn't exclude other sections. The linker will use its default rules to continue outputting all the other sections (including .rodata, .data, and .bss) after .text.
